# Problem creating new packages, error in workspace

Tags: ros, roscreate-pkg, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Creating new packages,typing the following comand :

```
$ roscreate-pkg std_msgs rospy roscpp
```

Below The lines:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
WARNING: current working directory is not on ROS_PACKAGE_PATH!
Please update your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Created package directory /home/iohan/rosws_tutorial/test
Created include directory /home/iohan/rosws_tutorial/test/include/test
Created cpp source directory /home/iohan/rosws_tutorial/test/src
Created package file /home/iohan/rosws_tutorial/test/Makefile
Created package file /home/iohan/rosws_tutorial/test/manifest.xml
Created package file /home/iohan/rosws_tutorial/test/CMakeLists.txt
Created package file /home/iohan/rosws_tutorial/test/mainpage.dox

Please edit test/manifest.xml and mainpage.dox to finish creating your package
```

So,I think the problem is in the creation the my workspace, but I followed all steps the tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays, I'm with errors the creation the my workspace.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42750/problem-creating-new-packages,-error-in-workspace./) by [Iohan Goncalves](https://answers.ros.org/users/3113/iohan-goncalves/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the creation of new packages, you should build a sandbox (see section 2 in the overlays tutorial).

```
mkdir ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
rosws set ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
```

After resourcing your setup.bash, you can should be ablte to create new packages there withour errors:

```
cd ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
roscreate-pkg std_msgs rospy roscpp
```

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1